# Cassandra : Rows missing from table after CQLSSTableWriter / sstableloader

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am struggling with a problem where a straightforward combination of a java app (that prepares sstables using the CQLSSTableWriter api) in combination with sstableloader fails to insert all rows.

The only suspect message I see during the creation of the sstables is

> [Reference-Reaper:1] ERROR o.a.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref - LEAK
>   DETECTED: a reference
>   (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@4651731d) to class
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@1452490935:Memory@[7f89dc05adc0..7f89dc05dfc0)
>   was not released before the reference was garbage collected

The sstableloader does not list anything suspect. After the load completes the number of rows does not match.

I checked key uniqueness and that does not seem to be the issue.

Anyone any thoughts on how to go about fixing this?

Many thanks indeed!

Peter

Comment: What cql version are you generating?

Comment: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11.908 | DSE 4.8.2 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]

Comment: can you confirm that the data is present in the sstables you are building? Do they show up in sstable2json?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Have not used sstable2json so I will have to do some digging.